# C# how to cast object to a type returned from GetType()

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, reflection, pinvoke

```
// Assuming this object is allocated somewhere else
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {1, "One"},
    {2, "Two"}
};

// allocate a handle for it so it won't get destroyed by GC
var handle1 = GCHandle.Alloc(dict);
// Get internal representation of this object
IntPtr ptrObj = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle1);


// Assuming now we are in another module
var handle2 = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptrObj); // Get handle from IntPtr of this object
var objDict = handle2.Target; // Get object

// How to convert it back to Dictionary?
// When debug, I know its type is Dictionary<int, string>,
// but how I can know here?
// This conversion is not working
var myDict = (Dictionary<object, object>)objDict;

// Anyway to cast it from GetType()?
var myDict = (objDict.GetType())objDict;
```

In one module, I created a dictionary and convert to **IntPtr** (for PInvoke call).
In another module, I get the dictionary object from **IntPtr**, which is a generic **object**. How can I convert back to it original type so that I can use it like this:

```
var myDict = (objDict.GetType())objDict; // Assuming this works
var count = myDict.Count; // Get element count
```

Comment: You can't. That's not how casting works. Casting is done for the sake of the compiler. How can the compiler know what type you're casting as if the result of `GetType` won't be known until run time? The whole point of casting is to specify that something will definitely be a specific type so treat it as that type in subsequent code. How could what you want to do accomplish that?

Comment: If you know for a fact that the type of the object will be `Dictionary<int, string>` then that is the type you should cast as, i.e. `var myDict = (Dictionary<int, string>)objDict;`. If that cast doesn't work then the object isn't that type, plain and simple.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with generics so I have removed the tag.

Comment: The runtime type is **Dictionary<int, string>**, but I only know it is an **object** at compile time. If convert to the type returned by **GetType()** is not possible, is there anyway to convert to **Dictionary<object, object>**? I just want to use its members at compile time without reflection.

Comment: @John I think I made it very clear in the question comment. I said it's created in another module, it is passed as **IntPtr**. I use it in another module, I can convert it back to **object**, in the runtime, I know it is a **Dictionary<int, string>**, but I want to use it as a dictionary at compile time. It's possible to get its type via **GetType()** at compile time, it's just the language feature doesn't provide a way to use it at compile time. Another way is to convert to **Dictionary<object, object>**, but I can't make the conversion directly as well.

Comment: I use **Dictionary<int, string>** just as an example, it can be **Dictionary<string, string>**, or **Dictionary<int, int>**. Its type is known at runtime or via **GetType()** at compile time. I want to use it like **Dictionary<TKey, TVal> d = (Dictionary<TKey, TVal>)(objDict)**, the problem here is I don't know there is a way to replace **TKey** or **TVal** with some type returned from **GetType()**.

Comment: Thanks @John for pointing out that **GetType** is for runtime NOT for compile time. OK. In this case, is there any easy way to convert **object** to **Dictionary<object, object>**? I will get runtime exception when I do: "Unable to cast object of type Dictionary<int, string> to type Dictionary<object, object>"

Comment: You can't cast something as a type that it isn't. If you want the basic dictionary functionality without knowing the specific generic type then cast as [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=net-6.0). The compiler will then allow all members of that interface in subsequent code.

Comment: Thanks @John. Yeah, I think **IDictionary** is exactly what I want. The purpose of the **cast** effort in this post is just for accessing basic dictionary functionality.

Comment: @benyu - If you have a resolution then post it as an answer. Don't edit the question with the answer. This site works by marking answers as accepted. Your question will not be of as much value without an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity. I just saw the **Answer** section. Previously, I didn't see something like that, that's why I put answer in it. Will remove it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution here seems to be to cast as type `IDictionary`. The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class implements that interface so it will provide the basic, common functionality regardless of the type of the keys and values.

```cs
var handle2 = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptrObj);
var myDict = (IDictionary)handle2.Target;
```

You can then, for instance, pass a key as an `object` and get a value back as an `object`:

```cs
var value = myDict[key];
```